# Identify post or page in wordpress and when to use both

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordress.. I need to create a wordpress site.. I am little confused when I use post and when I use page? How to identify whether the site should be pages or posts??

Comment: you have to go with wordress document and WordPress community website.

Comment: Its not a document.. I need to create a website like some company websites using wordpress

Comment: For make companies website you can use Pages, and Custom Templates for Pages, for bloging system you can use posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post is very usefull for you for make [Company website in Wordpress](https://en.support.wordpress.com/making-a-business-website/)

There are very key differences between posts and pages in your WordPress site.

#### About Posts

Posts are entries listed in reverse chronological order on the site homepage or on the posts page if you have set one in Reading Settings. If you have created any sticky posts, those will appear before the other posts. Posts can be found in the Archives, Categories, Recent Posts, and other widgets. Posts are also displayed in the RSS feed of the site. You can control how many posts are displayed at a time in the Reading Settings.

If you want your posts to appear on a page other than your home page, see Front Page.

#### About Pages

Pages are static and are not listed by date. Pages do not use tags or categories. An About page is the classic example. Pages can be displayed in the sidebar using the Pages widget, and some themes display pages in the navigation at the top of the site.

#### How many can I have?

There is no limit on the number of posts or pages you can have.

#### How do I post to a Page?

All posts will appear on the main posts page, but you can also display specific posts on category pages with our custom menus feature. If you want, you can change the default page for posts to appear by changing Reading Settings in the Dashboard. This will likely require changing your Front page as well.

Reference from [Wordpress Community](https://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/content/posts-vs-pages/)

Comment: If I have one wordpress site, How can i find the content should  be post or page??

Comment: you are making site from scratch or working on existing site?

Comment: I have added useful link in my answer

Comment: I need to make a new site not working on existing site.. In some of the wordpress sites, I don't know how to identify its a pages or post??

Comment: if you like answer then don't forget to up vote it.:)

Comment: Thanks, but you have marked as correct but not up voted :)